# App doesn't show my upvote, so I upvote -- and now it's "locked in"

Tags: bug, android-app

To reproduce:

1. upvote an answer with 0 current votes
2. edit the question

Expected behavior: answer shows 1 vote
Actual behavior: answer shows 0 votes

You will know that the server already received your upvote because if you  upvote again it will say that your vote is locked in.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: Nexus 4

  - OS Version: 5.1.1 (2237560)